# error "ETXTBSY: text file is busy" on npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm, homestead

When running `npm install [any package]` or even `npm install` on homestead I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rmdir '/home/vagrant/valemus-shop-starter/valemus-shop/node_modules/fsevents'
```

Debug log can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/martijnimhoff/118aab71ef9fe4ceb9b97be03e33f1df)

- Box 'laravel/homestead' (v3.0.0)
- Node: v8.2.1
- NPM: 5.3.0

I tried removing the `fsevents` directory, however, it doesn't exist.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into the same thing on Windows 10 + VirtualBox (VBox) + Vagrant + Laravel Homestead when I wanted to change to react frontend.

And after much search and trial and error, this solution worked for me, maybe it works for you as well.

Halted the vagrant:

```
vagrant halt
```

Added the following into the configure section of the Vagrantfile in the Homestead dir

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
  end
```

started the cmd as admin

then `vagrant up`

and `vagrant ssh`

cd to development dir

then removed the node_modules dir by `rm -rf node_modules/` *if any*

and then ran the `sudo npm install && npm run dev`

and the whole thing was installed without any warnings or errors.

This is the result of two hours reading :)

**Edit:**

If your problem is not solved and you have the mentioned setup you can use another solution:

Install the Node on your windows machine too

Then cd to your development directory and run the `npm install` from the Windows and the you'll have the same result.

You can also initiate the `npm run watch` from a windows cmd afterwards.

This helped me to lift the load from the VM and let the Windows do the watch and receive the notifications of the `npm run watch` in Windows.

Cheers

Comment: This doesn't work for me, however the error is non critical. I can run `gulp` fine after `npm install`.

Comment: Need to update Node `$ sudo npm install n -g` and `$ sudo n stable` prior to do these steps

Comment: Have same setup as noted here, couldn't get anything to work - had to default to npm on Windows

Comment: if the above doesn't work, you can also run:  `$  sudo yarn install` and without any problem `$ npm run dev`

Answer (score 13):

Downgraing the npm version to 5.7.1 did the trick for me.

Command used to downgrade: `npm install -g npm@5.7.1`

I am using Win10, Vagrant, Ubuntu v14.04 and Node v8.11.4

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Windows 10, Vagrant, CentOs 7.5. Any idea why we get these errors with the newer versions?

Comment: Worked for me as well! CentOS 7 running in Vagrant on Windows 8.1. I downgraded to npm version 6 (using nvm) and the issues went away.

Comment: Worked for me on Vagrant scotch-box-pro

Answer (score 10):

Just issue "npm install" in Windows instead of in Homestead. Of course, you need to have npm for windows installed to do that.

Comment: Author's OS is not Windows.

Comment: Ok. My point is to issue "npm install" in the host os, not in the guest os. This solve the problem that I have experienced. However, for the global package, you need issue "npm install -g {package}" in the guest os.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonWang  `npm install` needs to be run on the host indeed. Same for `npm run dev`

Comment: The problem though is that you now need to ensure that your Node version matches between your host and guest OS if you plan on actually using Node on your guest OS (for build tools etc)

Comment: Doh! Deleted my node_modules, force cleared the cache, almost reinstalled node completely before seeing this and realizing I was in ssh. Thanks for saving me even more wasted time.

Answer (score 8):

The same thing happened to me

My environment is linux

fsevents is a module dedicated to mac

Please try the following command

npm install --no-optional

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this problem on my Windows 10 machine with Homestead a lot of. And After a lot of effort I solved it with that way;

delete your node_modules folder.

You run this commands on your **windows terminal:**

```
npm install --no-bin-links (After some experience it is necessary for virtual machines)
npm rebuild --no-bin links
```

Generally it works after these commands, but if you have take this error

> "Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:"

please run this command on your **Homestead Terminal** for installing node Sass for Linux.

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

if it is not work, try use yarn. Delete node modules folder package.json.lock and yarn.lock (if there) files and type

```
yarn install
```

If all of them is not save you, **use all npm commands out of the virtual machine.**  It will be work.

I hope this helps you...

Answer (score 7):

I was still getting an error, even after doing following

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, 
     "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
  end
```

as suggested by [Babak Bandpey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7734412/babak-bandpey)

It turned out that there was another annoying problem of file path character limit. This happens quite often if you are using a node module with long name. You can easily solve this by following these steps after vagrant ssh into linux vm:

1. Create ‘node_modules’ folder in your home folder
   `mkdir ~/node_modules`
2. Add symbolic link to the ‘node_modules’ folder you just created inside your project folder

   `ln -sf ~/node_modules /vagrant/your-project-folder`

This solution will ensure that all the node modules are stored inside home directory instead of synced folder. Original source : https://blog.rudylee.com/2014/10/27/symbolic-links-with-vagrant-windows/

Hope it helps somone having similar issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also struggle finding a solution for this but here it is.

1. Make sure to update node to latest version

To update, you can install n

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Then just :

```
sudo n latest
```

2. Set Node scripts to use environment variables across platforms

In vagrant run :

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install 
npm run dev
```

That did the trick , although i spent an entire day finding the right solution (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 3):

I had problem with "npm install" too, I use Windows 10. Finally I got it fixed, what I did is that I exited from "vagrant ssh" and run "vagrant box update", then "npm install" worked. Notice that I ran "vagrant box update" and "npm install" out of "vagrant ssh". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

i had to delete the node_modules folder first, then i did

```
sudo chmod a+x .
```

for making sure i got the privilege to do anything on the machine, then i

```
sudo npm install --no-bin-links
```

no bin links is required in vagrant from my experience because these VM don't support bin links (correct me if im wrong). Then i just

```
sudo npm run dev
```

at this point some people might encounter no cross-env found error. In that case, just delete cross-env in package.json file and run it again. It worked for me but some people still encounter the same problem. Might worth to give it a shot.

Comment: Need to update Node `$ sudo npm install n -g` and `$ sudo n stable` prior to do these steps

Comment: `sudo chmod a+x .` - in which directory  must I be? the _parent_ of node_modules ? or _inside_ node_modules ?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem than yours, @AzharKhattak, except that it took place on a Virtualbox offering a *Debian* session with a shared `/Dev` folder, existing also on the *Windows* host.

In my case, however, the action:

```bash
$ sudo ln -sf ~/node_modules /Dev/myproject/node_modules/
```

failed with a message:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/Dev/myproject/node_modules/node_modules': Operation not permitted
```

I had to move my project in a not shared directory at all, `/Devout` I'd created for it.