# NPM Install Error | Text File is Busy, Unlink

Tags: laravel, npm-install

Getting this error when running `sudo npm install --force --no-bin-links` within project folder. Below is the error I'm receiving. It looks like it keeps renaming some of the nodes. I go into the actual folder and remove the #s at the end, but when I run the install again, it just re-adds them...not sure what's going on.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9979 this might help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678817/error-etxtbsy-text-file-is-busy-on-npm-install Also have a look at the answers.

Comment: Try closing any text editors you have open and running the command again. I run into this issue sometimes, specifically with the Atom text editor

Answer (score 0):

"ETXTBSY is a file sharing violation at the system level, and it indicates that another process has the file already opened and holds the lock for it." ([source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21580422))

It means that npm is trying to overwrite a locked file. You have to stop the process holding the lock to be able to overwrite that file.

The process PID can be found with

`fuser -u <package.json.somenumber`