# Can't install any encryption packages on node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, cryptojs

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 via Vagrant+Virtualbox on Windows 10.
npm is working great and I haven't had any problems installing any modules.
A few days ago I tried installing bcrypt but the process failed. I tried all of the solutions I could find on stackoverflow threads, and the only one that worked was installing using yarn.
I won't get into it, but I prefer bcrypt to be installed via npm.
Then I tried installing bcryptjs, crypto-js and jsonwebtoken, all FAIL! 
So for some reason all of the cryptography related modules fail when installing via npm...
I tried updating node and npm to the latest version but the I wasn't able to install anything.
Going back to npm v 5.7.1 got me back to where i was before: I can install everything but cryptography related modules.

The error I get trying to install bcrypt:

```
688 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant    /node/test8/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist/package.json.1450451485'
694 error path /vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist/package.json.1450451485
695 error code ENOENT
696 error errno -2
697 error syscall open
698 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist/package.json.1450451485'
699 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

The error(s) I get trying to install bcryptjs:

```
354 warn rollback Rolling back bcryptjs@2.4.3 failed (this is probably harmless): ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json.3007922196'
360 verbose stack Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json.3007922196' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json'
366 error path /vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json.3007922196
367 error code ETXTBSY
368 error errno -26
369 error syscall rename
370 error ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json.3007922196' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/bcryptjs/package.json'
```

The error(s) I get trying to install crypto-js:

```
359 verbose stack Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json.3321474119' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json'
365 error path /vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json.3321474119
366 error code ETXTBSY
367 error errno -26
368 error syscall rename
369 error ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json.3321474119' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json'
```

The error(s) I get trying to install jsonwebtoken:

```
597 verbose stack Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/jwa/package.json.1518470635' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/jwa/package.json'
603 error path /vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/jwa/package.json.1518470635
604 error code ETXTBSY
605 error errno -26
606 error syscall rename
607 error ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/jwa/package.json.1518470635' -> '/vagrant/node/test8/node_modules/jwa/package.json'
```

any idea what's causing all this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases in which NPM fails to find a file. Try the following and let me know:

1. Run the command `vagrant halt` to halt the vagrant
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
3. Update the NPM and Node to the latest version
4. Run `npm cache clean --force`
5. Now try to install
6. Once everything is done, you can up the vagrant by running `vagrant up` and if you wanted SSH, then run this command after up, `vagrant ssh`

More information related to the similar issues can be seen [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=This%20is%20related%20to%20npm%20not%20being%20able%20to%20find%20a%20file)

Might be useful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091934/2520628

Also on a side note, some modules require a different version of NPM, [see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#version-compatibility)

So my guess is that you might be trying to install an incompatible version

Comment: Thank you Tejashwi for your quick reply. I updated node to v 10.1.0 and npm to v 6.2. Couldn't install anything again! Reverted back to npm 5.7.1 and now I can install every module but bcrypt. Will do without it I guess, bcryptjs should suffice.